# How to handle the images efficiently as assets in pubspec.yaml?

Tags: image, flutter, dart, assets

So I have my project that has 20 folders and each folder has 10 images, I need to animate the images.

Generally we assign images in flutter like below,

```
image1.jpg

asset:
  - assets/images1.jpg
```

So Do I have to assign all these images as assets like above? Or is there any way to handle large set of local images in flutter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To include all assets under a directory, specify the directory name with the / character at the end:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

Note that only files located directly in the directory are included. To add files located in subdirectories, create an entry per directory.

Source: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images

Answer (score 0):

You can create images sub-folder inside assets folder and can directly include/import that folder in pubspec.yaml file like this:

```
flutter:   
   assets:     
    - assets/images/
```